IR Library for getting HEX for universal remote (K-1028E)
I am currently using an ESP32-DevKitC-32E with ESP-IDF v5.2.2 in Visual Studio Code. My setup includes a TSMP98000 photodetector circuit and an IR LED driver circuit. I aim to capture HEX codes from button presses on a Universal AC Remote (K-1028E).
I have used the NEC remote infrared RMT example (https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/peripherals/rmt/ir_nec_transceiver) and receive NEC frames as shown below:
NEC frame start---
{1:3},{0:688}
{1:31},{0:172}
{1:7949},{0:7349}
{1:3},{0:75}
{1:10},{0:166}
{1:8377},{0:0}
---NEC frame end: Unknown NEC frame

NEC frame start---
{1:3},{0:1054}
{1:678},{0:474}
{1:3},{0:87}
{1:266},{0:268}
{1:144},{0:171}
{1:32},{0:298}
{1:2095},{0:167}
{1:0},{0:167}
---NEC frame end: Unknown NEC frame

However, I want to obtain precise HEX values (e.g., 0x41F5BBD1) or similar to those address and command. I have following questions to resolve my issue?

How can I find the exact connection of each button press event?
Could anyone assist me in achieving similar functionality with the ESP-IDF setup? Thank you.

